# GAP Software: ComplementIntMatWithTransforms v/s ComplementIntMat

Tags: group-cohomology, gap

I am trying to implement the GAP algorithm given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.06538.pdf to compute the group cohomology of finite groups. One of the functions they use is "ComplementIntMatWithTransforms" (page 12 of the linked paper). When I tried to use this function on GAP I got the following error.

RuntimeError: Gap produced error output
Error, Variable: 'ComplementIntMatWithTransforms' must have a value

I am unable to find this function in the GAP documentation. I did find the function "ComplementIntMat" (this is 25.1-6 at https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap25.html). I don't get any errors with this function. However, without a documentation for "ComplementIntMatWithTransforms" I am not sure whether these two functions are the same. If someone could clarify this that would be great!

I am using GAP within SageMath 9.6.

Answer (score 2):

`ComplementIntMatWithTransforms` is not a standard GAP function, nor does it seem in any of the packages distributed with the system.
I suppose it is a private function, written by the authors of the article, possibly simply keepingtrack of the base change in `ComplementIntMat`.
Your best option is likely to contact said authors and ask them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will contact the authors and add an answer once I get this clarified.